# Angular 4 not rendering properly on IE 11

Tags: javascript, angular, polyfills

I am trying to get my Angular app work properly on IE.
Its building on IE but not rendering properly.

**For Example :**

1. CSS styles not applied properly
2. Colors applied to SVG using style tags are missing
3. `*ngIf` applied to divs not working
4. Using `{{typescript variable}}` in HTML doesn't display text in few places and many more

Angular Version: 4.1.0

**Please note** : I tried running it with add on **polyfills** like shim for client but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Press F12 and check which compatibility mode it's running in?

Comment: Are you sure you are using [all required polyfills](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support) for the features you use?

Comment: @GSerg : I am not really sure on that. But something as simple as accessing typescript variable's value in html is also not working. Do I need any polyfill for that?

Comment: The ES6 polyfill is required. Are you using it? (Yes, missing ES6 features can stop you from doing anything including updating variables.)

Comment: Yes I have imported that in my polyfills.ts file by adding "import 'core-js/es6';"..Is that the correct way to include it? How can I check if it is loading on IE?

Comment: You can check the network tab and see if the corresponding file is downloaded or not

Comment: @AlexBeugnet : The polyfills file is loading.

Comment: What module bundler do you use ? Angular-CLI with Webpack ?Honestly, I have no idea for your issue... I would check the compatibility mode from the browser as @EvanKnowles mentionned, but apart from that...

Comment: @AlexBeugnet : Yes I use CLI with webpack

Comment: @GSerg : ES6 polyfill is added..I am able to read the value of variables in HTML at few places..But at other places it fails miserably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally get this working by **adding a polyfill for IE** by following these steps :

1. Run **npm install --save classlist.js** which adds classlist to your node_modules 
   and dependency automatically gets added in package.json like this : 
   **"classlist.js":"^1.1.20150312"**
2. Add **import 'classlist.js';** to polyfills.ts file.

More information on missing polyfills for browser compatibilty for angular can be found here https://angular.io/guide/browser-support